# Npm install removing other packages in Ionic (I suspect its Yarn)

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, ionic3, yarnpkg

I recently had to install Yarn (via Homebrew) on my machine for a project I’m working on. After I installed Yarn and went back to my Ionic project, upon trying to install firebase into my project: `npm install --save firebase` I get the following: `+ firebase@4.3.1 added 22 packages and removed 35 packages`

I then see that some other packages in in my app.module.ts file are showing a red line saying `[ts] Cannot find module '@ionic-native/social-sharing'`. This happens for 3 other packages too. I don’t know what else is affected.

How can I fix this from happening? I tried to uninstall Yarn via homebrew: `brew uninstall yarn` but the issue still persists!

Here is my system info:

```
npm -v5.4.2
node -v6.11.2
```

ionic info in my project:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
Node       : v6.11.2
npm        : 5.4.2
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
```

Comment: try to reinstall node module `npm install`

Comment: Hi there, if I delete node modules and re-install I get the following error during `npm install`: `npm ERR! path /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-3a25ba7f/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-3a25ba7f/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2017-09-19T13_15_47_056Z-debug.log`